# How to enable chromedriver in ubuntu for python script?

Tags: 18.04, cron, selenium

For a scheduled task I want the selenium webdriver to be executed with python script.

I have tried the following solution:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117377/selenium-with-chromedriver-doesnt-start-via-cron

But it has not resolved the problem.

Location of chromdriver:

```
~/Documents/Python/Chromedriver/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify full paths in cron.

The next cron job includes:

- `DISPLAY` variable specified to access your display in case if you do not want to use [headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug). Use `$ env | grep DISPLAY` to get it.
- `PATH` variable with path to `chromedriver` specifying. I've copied `chromedriver` to `/usr/local/bin`
- Full path to `python3.8`
- Full path to python script

`$ crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/user/PycharmProjects/seleniumtest/seltest.py build
```

In your case specify path to your chromdriver location:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Documents/python/Chromedriver; /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/user/PycharmProjects/seleniumtest/seltest.py build
```

**Note:** I've created a python project in PyCharm using the next parameters:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The script is taken from [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Additionally I have been required to install some packages:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ pip3 install selenium
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
$ sudo cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks for you help